# Is it possible to add "move to another workspace" menu item to the Alt-spacebar menu as was present in Gnome3

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, workspaces

Under Ubuntu 20.04 Alt-Spacebar shows a menu option "Move to another Workspace", which lists all workspaces and allows a specific one to be selected. That's no longer present in 22.04. Can it be re-enabled? If not is there a short-cut that allows a specific workspace to be selected?

Additional info: I use 16 workspaces, so assignment of individual keys for workspace moving is not practical. Also the Super+Shift+PgUp/PgDn is tedious.  In addition it have a matrixed workspace enabled using gnome extensions. Super+Shift+PgUp/PgDn or drag and drop to/from the icon menu only works for the top row.

It's a pity this feature has gone as it it useful even without the use of a matrixed workspace.

Richard

Answer (score 0):

Implementing such menu item probably will require you to edit source code.

- The default shortcut keys <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp/Dn</kbd> will move your window one workspace right/left.
- Shortcut keys to move a window to a specific workspace (i.e., workspace with a specific number) can be set in "Settings", "Keyboard", "Keyboard Shortcuts", section "Navigation". This is only exposed for up to workspace 4. You can use `dconf-editor` instead if you also want to set keybindings for workspace 5 and higher. This may work best if you set a specific number of workspaces instead of using the dynamic workspaces (the default). This can be changed in "Settings" - "Multitasking" (for older versions of Gnome Shell via Gnome Tweaks).
- A menu where you can select the workspace where you want to move the window to does not anymore exist. For this, you can resort to dragging from the overview. Hit <kbd>Super</kbd> and drag windows to the tiny representations of all open workspaces in the top (or to the workspaces left or right).

Comment: Unfortunately I don't find Super+Shift+PgUp/PgDn reliable, but more importantly with 16 workspaces this is a real pain to use. Is there any good reason this was removed from the current version of gnome?

Comment: Actually there's another issue with the Super suggestions: it doesn't work well with a matrixed workspace. PgUp/Down and drag/drop only works for the current row of the matrix.

Comment: It will be important that you add this information to your question: if you fail to mention this, nobody is presumed to assume you may want a matrixed workspace. Within the current default design of Gnome, I guess a specific menu to switch workspaces was deemed superfluous. I do not even remember that feature, but then, I use workspaces very sparingly, only when a separate visual context is desired.